# Set Img Height and Width to 100% without scaling

Tags: html, css, height

I have this:

```
.home_post_cont { width: 228px; min-height: 331px;  }
.home_post_cont img { width: 228px; height: 331px; }
```

It then fits perfectly the container.

I want to have this:

```
.home_post_cont img { width: 100%; height: 100%; } /* In case container size changes */
```

But I only can set width OR height to 100%. I don't want the image to scale, so even if it is not scaled I want it to be 100% height and width of the container.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options if you want to save the original size of parent container and a formatting that does not point the height strictly.

First - postion:absolute, Try this for first option: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mynewbox/rm7jf6x4/4)

Second - use picture as a background. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mynewbox/rm7jf6x4/7/)

```css
.home_post_cont { 
    width: 228px; 
    min-height: 331px; 
    background-color: #f00;
    position: relative;}

.home_post_cont img { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;    
    position: absolute;
      top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='home_post_cont'>
    <img src="http://www.cnc3.co.tt/sites/default/files/content/Glee.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: you said:"I don't want the image to scale". Did you mean: "I want the image to keep the aspect ratio"?

Comment: No I don't want to keep the aspect ratio, I want it to fits container no matter what. Tried your jsfiddle and it does not work, see: http://jsfiddle.net/rm7jf6x4/3/

Comment: I see, so you have 2 options if you want to save the original size of parent container and formatting that does not point height strictly. First would be - postion:absolute, and the second would be  - use picture as a background. Try this for first option: http://jsfiddle.net/mynewbox/rm7jf6x4/4/

Comment: You're welcome, please, have a look, I made it with background.
http://jsfiddle.net/mynewbox/rm7jf6x4/7/

Comment: First solution is way better for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since the width will vary the least, you'll want to base the resize on that. As it seems you know, to keep the aspect ratio you can only set the size of one attribute.

```
.home_post_cont { width: 228px; min-height: 331px;  }
.home_post_cont img { max-width: 228px; max-height: auto; }
```